# In Pugh's analysis book, why are these metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Pugh introduces the notion of metric space in chapter 2 as follows

> Definition: A metric space is a set $X$ equipped with a metric $d$

Clear!

> For example, a metric space is $(\mathbb{R}, |x-y|)$, where $|\cdot|$
>   is the absolute value

Super clear!

> The following are also metric spaces

[image]

What!!!!!??? It is my first time doing analysis...

Can someone please illustrate just for a single example in the above figure as to what the set and the metric would be. For example, what would be the set $X$ and the metric $d$ used in the "closed spiral" figure?

Much thanks!

Comment: the topologist's sine circle has a topology induced from the euclidean plane:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve.
Can you see how it inherits its topology?

Comment: Pugh is being fanciful by drawing pictures and saying "these are metric spaces." Here, the most obvious metric in all these spaces is just your ruler - how you'd measure the distance between two points. This turns out to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different choices of metrics that make those sets become metric spaces.

The easiest choice for all of them is to consider them as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, and to use the induced metric, e.g. if I let $X$ be the closed spiral, I can let $d$ be the metric given by $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$, where $||x-y||$  is the usual distance in $\Bbb{R}^2$, i.e.
$$||x-y|| = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}.$$
This choice will work for all the sets, since they can all be considered a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Another possible choice for the closed spiral $X$ is to let $d(x,y)$ be the shortest distance *following the spiral* between $x$ and $y$, i.e. the length of the curve segment on the spiral connecting the two points $x$ and $y$.

The moral is that when the author says that these are examples of metric spaces, he should really mention what metrics he has in mind, as a bunch of different metrics are possible on each set.

Edit: You were also asking what the set $X$ is in the closed spiral case. I don't think it's important to describe it in exact terms in this case. You can just make a drawing like the author did, and say that your set $X$ consists of all points on that curve.

Also, it's hard to give the exact parametrization from his drawing alone, but it could be something like $r(t) = \arctan(t)$ for $t\geq 0$ in polar coordinates, or $r(t) = f(t)$ for any increasing $f$ that has a horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider all of these sets as subsets of the euclidean plane, which is a metric space with euclidean distance $d$. Restricting $d$ to these each of these sets provides a metric for each of them.

Comment: So any squiggle on the plane will be a metric space? I can accept that the metric will be say the absolute value of the difference between the two points, but what about the set $X$? Is it legit if I just leave it at $X = \{\text{squiggles}\subset \mathbb{R}^2\}$

Comment: No, the author is leaving out the details of how the sets could be defined specifically. For example, the Hawaiian earring could be defined as the union, for $n \geq 1$, of the circles centred at $(\pm 1/n, 0)$ with radius $1/n$. (This is not exactly the same as the illustration, but it has the same essential features.)

Comment: @FemaleTank Well this is sort of a philosophical point, but consider this: You first have a set, and as soon as you 'draw' the set (as squiggles, let's say), you already presuppose some notion of distance (proximity in general).

Comment: @FemaleTank By the way, all the 'squiggles' Pugh gives have deterministic descriptions, for instance the Hawaiian earring is the one point union of countably many circles with decreasing radii, so you can construct them from more elementary metric spaces (like line segments and circles) via set operations and some shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, these are simply subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the induced distance.

Here is a possible definition of the closed outward spiral. It is the union of the unit circle and the polar curve $\theta = 1/(1-r)$, for $0 \leq r<1$.

This is only a reasonable approximation of what you see in the figure. Other choices are possible, so long as they have the same essential features from a topological standpoint. What this means is that if I pick a metric space $X_1$ and a friend picks a metric space $X_2$, then there is a bijection $f$ between $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that open sets in one correspond to open sets in the other via $f$. (A mapping $f$ with this property is called a *homeomorphism*.)